# CRC32 in binascii.crc32 outputs variable checksum length: 8-9-10 digits

Tags: python, crc32, binascii

Is it correct behavior that binascii.crc32 outputs different checksum lengths: sometimes 8 digits, sometimes 9 or 10. I use it for an array of bytes: <700 bytes.

The code:

```
print(binascii.crc32(array_of_bytes))
```

Results:

```
3844368964
1383389069
132823901
3963271002
620395401
596927826
706646509
1571319956
243595751
908768330
```

Comment: A 32-bit number can appear as anything *up to* 10 digits in decimal.  It could even be a single digit, although that's extremely unlikely here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct behavior. All of them are 32-bits long. Just some have more zeros in the most significant bits. On average, 23% of them will be nine digits or shorter. 2.3% will be eight digits or shorter.